# Including a Header in Pre Compiled Header AND Outside of it in my Class Header File

Tags: c++, include, precompiled-headers

I have searched for a while on this, but I keep getting answers that do not answer this specific scenario.

I have a class called `VisibleGameObject`. I am wondering what happens if I put my normal includes in the header (so that other developers can use the same class), and put the same include in my pre compiled header `stdafx.h`
I don't want developers dependent on my pch.

```
// VisibleGameObject.h

#pragma once
#include "SFML\Graphics.hpp"
#include <string>

class VisibleGameObject
{
public:
    VisibleGameObject();
    virtual ~VisibleGameObject();

    virtual void Load( std::string filename );
    virtual void Draw( sf::RenderWindow & window );

    virtual void SetPosition( float x, float y );

private:
    sf::Sprite  _sprite;
    sf::Image _image;
    std::string _filename;
    bool _isLoaded;
};
```

Implementaion:

```
// VisibleGameObject.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "VisibleGameObject.h"

...
```

PCH:

```
// stdafx.h
#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>


// TODO: reference additional headers your program requires here
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
```

When I build my project (after I have compiled once), does `#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>` get recompiled every time? Because it is included in the header file of this class. I think what happens is that the pch is included first in the cpp file's translation unit and then `#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>` is include guarded so the pch works normally and my include is ignored. In Visual Studio, it is an error to not include the pch first. I just want to confirm this behaviour. Does the pch get used normally and no `<SFML/Graphics.hpp>` code is recompiled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the author of the header has any salt at all, then no, it won't be recompiled.

The PCH includes the full definition, including the `#ifndef, #define, #endif` include guard logic. During PCH-creation the file will be pulled in, compiled, and the include guard identifier formally defined. In your source that follows any `#include "stdax.h"` all that precompiled content is slurped in. The source **will** include the suspect header for compilation. However, the preprocessor will skip all the content once the include guard's `#ifndef` id is found as defined. Note: It *is* possible it can be recompiled for a translation unit that specifically has PCH turned *off*, but I doubt you've done that.

In short, you're doing it correctly, and your assessment is accurate.